# Erro ao instalar o laravel 5.6 com Docker

Tags: laravel-5, docker

Estou tentando configurar o `laravel 5.6` em imagem do *Docker*, mas ao executar o comando:

```
 docker run -it --rm  \
     -v $(pwd):/app {user_dockerHub}/docker-laravel \ 
     composer create-project laravel/laravel app
```

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

```
Problem 1
- phpunit/phpunit 7.2.2 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.2.3 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.2.4 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.2.5 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.2.6 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.2.7 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.2.x-dev requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.3.0 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.3.1 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.3.2 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.3.3 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.3.4 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.3.5 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.3.x-dev requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.4.x-dev requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.2.0 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.6 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.2.1 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.6 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.0.3 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.0.x-dev requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.1.0 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.1.1 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.1.2 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.1.3 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.1.4 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.1.5 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.1.x-dev requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.0.0 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.0.1 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/phpunit 7.0.2 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ^6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.x-dev].
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.x-dev requires ext-xmlwriter * -> the requested PHP extension xmlwriter is missing from your system.
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.7 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> the requested PHP extension xmlwriter is missing from your system.
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.6 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> the requested PHP extension xmlwriter is missing from your system.
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.5 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> the requested PHP extension xmlwriter is missing from your system.
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.4 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> the requested PHP extension xmlwriter is missing from your system.
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.3 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> the requested PHP extension xmlwriter is missing from your system.
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.2 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> the requested PHP extension xmlwriter is missing from your system.
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.1 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> the requested PHP extension xmlwriter is missing from your system.
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.0 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> the requested PHP extension xmlwriter is missing from your system.
- Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ^7.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.0.x-dev, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 7.1.3, 7.1.4, 7.1.5, 7.1.x-dev, 7.2.0, 7.2.1, 7.2.2, 7.2.3, 7.2.4, 7.2.5, 7.2.6, 7.2.7, 7.2.x-dev, 7.3.0, 7.3.1, 7.3.2, 7.3.3, 7.3.4, 7.3.5, 7.3.x-dev, 7.4.x-dev].



To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php7/php.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_ctype.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_curl.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_dom.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_json.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_mbstring.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_mcrypt.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_opcache.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_openssl.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_pdo.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_session.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_tokenizer.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/00_xml.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/01_mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/01_pdo_pgsql.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/01_pdo_sqlite.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/01_phar.ini
- /etc/php7/conf.d/02_pdo_mysql.ini



You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk --update add --no-cache \
    nginx \
    curl \
    supervisor \
    php7 \
    php7-ctype \
    php7-curl \
    php7-dom \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-json \
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-mcrypt \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-pdo_pgsql \
    php7-pdo_sqlite \
    php7-phar \
    php7-session \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-xml
RUN rm -Rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod -R 755 /app
EXPOSE 82 445
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

Já procurei pela web, testei possíveis soluções e não tive um resultado satisfatório.

Se alguém já passou por esse problema e quiser compartilhar eu agradeço desde já.

**Referença:** 
[Criando uma aplicação Laravel com Docker](http://petronetto.com.br/2017/05/08/criando-uma-aplicacao-laravel-com-docker)

Comment: Está executando um container e instalando dentro, se sim, quais comandos está executando? Se puder, adiciona mais detalhes do seu problema. Se estiver criando sua imagem, posta o *Dockerfile* completo que tá usando. Ou pode apenas usar uma imagem já disponível no *Docker Hub*.

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim desconsidere o comentário anterior. **Está executando um container e instalando dentro, se sim, quais comandos está executando? R.:** docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/app {user_dockerHub}/docker-laravel composer create-project laravel/laravel app. A forma de configuração do ambiente que estou fazendo é a mesma do link de referença.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando com calma, o seu erro é **idêntico** a um erro reportado nos comentários da sua [referência](http://petronetto.com.br/2017/05/08/criando-uma-aplicacao-laravel-com-docker):

```
phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.7 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> the requested PHP extension xmlwriter is missing from your system.
```

É a dependências **xmlwriter** que não foi adicionada a sua imagem.

No seu *Dockerfile*, adicione: `php7-xmlwriter`na lista de dependência e faça o *build* da imagem novamente. Quando executar a nova imagem vai funcionar corretamente.

Comment: **Tuxpilgrim**, fiz o que vc pediu e funcionou perfeitamente. Valeu parça, Deus abençoe.

Answer (score -3):

eu prefiro fazer a instalação normal do Laravel e depois aplicar o Docker no Laravel.

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4.22-apache
COPY . /var/www/html
USER root
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
COPY ./vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY .envkube .env
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

o arquivo que é invocado pelo Dockerfile é

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Use os comando abaixo para ver o exemplo rodando no Docker

> docker build -t teste-php .
>
> docker run -it -p 8011:80 teste-php